protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable
I been searching for whole Internet but I still dont know where to get protoc-gen-grpc
The error is observed when I creating the stub from a proto file.
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=./common/v1/ --python_out=./common/v1/ --grpc_out=./common/v1/ --plugin=grpc_python_plugin common/v1/common.proto
protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable 
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.


Try removing the --grpc_out flag
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=./common/v1/ --grpc_python_out=./common/v1/ --plugin=grpc_python_plugin common/v1/common.proto


python -m grpc_tools.protoc --help

